# Android - TFLite OD - Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (normalized_input_image_tensor) with 307200 bytes from a Java Buffer with 4320000 bytes

Tags: android, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to run my own custom model for object detection. I created my dataset from  Google cloud - Vision (https://console.cloud.google.com/vision/) (I boxed and labeled the images) and it looks like this:

[image]

After training the model, I downloaded the TFLite files  (labelmap.txt, model.tflite and a json file) from here:

[image]

Then, I added them to the Android Object Detection example ( https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android ) .

[image]

But when I run the project it crashes:

```
2020-07-12 18:03:05.160 14845-14883/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: inference
    Process: org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection, PID: 14845
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (normalized_input_image_tensor) with 307200 bytes from a Java Buffer with 4320000 bytes.
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.throwIfSrcShapeIsIncompatible(Tensor.java:423)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Tensor.setTo(Tensor.java:189)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run(NativeInterpreterWrapper.java:154)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(Interpreter.java:343)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.recognizeImage(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:197)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity$2.run(DetectorActivity.java:182)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
```

I tried changing the parameters **TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED** to false and **labelOffset** to 0, and also I modified this line from the TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java to     `d.imgData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(_4_ * d.inputSize * d.inputSize * 3 * numBytesPerChannel);` (I replaced 1 for 4)

I am new to this, I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand and resolve the error. Thank you!

---

**Update**:
Here are the tflite files : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11QT8CgaYF2EseORgGCceh4DT80_pMiFM?usp=sharing  (I don't care if the model recognize correctly the squares and circles, I just want to check if it compiles on the android app and then I will improve it)

Comment: Welcome back! Nice to see that you have made progress. Error prompts for error in input size. If you have uploaded somewhere your project I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: haha yes, it's me again. I used exactly the object detection example here https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android.  And here is the class where I modified the parameters https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/DetectorActivity.java

Comment: When you trained the model on google cloud what dimensions did you use? Here at the example is 300x300

Comment: That's the problem, I don't find the way to know what architecture is used to generate the model, and I don't know if it's possible to change it. I configured the model for "object detection" so I believe that the model has the correct architecture and parameters.

Comment: There! I updated the post with the link with files, just in case someone else needs them. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I will give it a try! During that use https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/ to get used to it

Comment: As u can see the input is 1x320x320x3......... So use 1x320x320x3x4 for 

`1 * d.inputSize * d.inputSize * 3 * numBytesPerChannel`

Comment: Nop, still the same error, although it changed the buffer size
 Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (normalized_input_image_tensor) with 307200 bytes from a Java Buffer with 1228800 bytes.

Comment: Something changed though!! :):) ... Somewhere there, there is the error. I can not do much without code. If it is possible upload all code to a github repo

Comment: As I am ready to sleep I see that if you divide 1228800/307200 you get 4...So use 1x320x320x3x1...and tell me what you get

Comment: nice!! it worked with 1x320x320x3x1! The 'TF_OD_API_IS_QUANTIZED' attribute is the one that multiples *4 (true) or *1(false), so I changed it and it worked like you said :D Finaallllyyyy. Please post your answer so I can accept this answer, you're the best!

Comment: Nice!! I will do it tomorrow..I am sleeping in a minute

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a superb visualization tool that is called [Netron](https://lutzroeder.github.io/netron/) . I used your .tflite file and the input of your model is:

[image]

So at your code at line where you calculate bytebuffer

> 1 * d.inputSize * d.inputSize * 3 * numBytesPerChannel

you have to input

> 1*    320       *    320      * 3 *       1

the last  "1"  is for uint8....if you had floats you should put "4".

Answer (score 1):

After I change TensorImage DataType from UINT8 to FLOAT32, it works.

```
 val tfImageBuffer = TensorImage(DataType.UINT8)
 ->
 val tfImageBuffer = TensorImage(DataType.FLOAT32)
```