# Cannot copy to TensorflowLite tensor (serving_default_conv2d_input:0) with 9216 bytes from a Java buffer with 110592 bytes

Tags: java, android-studio, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

[I was trying to convert a TensorFlow model into the TFlite model and integrate it into an app using android studio. When I run the app the following error pops up, I think it's related to the compatibility of the size of the java buffer in my app and the tensor size in my model.. I tried changing the size of the input images in the model but it didn't work ]

error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy to TensorflowLite tensor (serving_default_conv2d_input:0) with 9216 bytes from a Java buffer with 110592 bytes.

Comment: Possible duplicate to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62866577/android-tflite-od-cannot-copy-to-a-tensorflowlite-tensor-normalized-input-i/62888294#62888294