# Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (serving_default_efficientnetb0_input:0) with 110592 bytes from a Java Buffer with 1080000 bytes

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow-lite

Im working on a Sign-language recognition app.
I get an error saying "Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (serving_default_efficientnetb0_input:0) with 110592 bytes from a Java Buffer with 1080000 bytes".

Here is the code for convert Bitmap to Byte Buffer

```
private ByteBuffer convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
    int quant=1;
    int size_images=INPUT_SIZE;
    if(quant==0){
        byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1*size_images*size_images*3);
    }
    else {
        byteBuffer=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4*1*size_images*size_images*3);
    }
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    int[] intValues=new int[size_images*size_images];
    bitmap.getPixels(intValues,0,bitmap.getWidth(),0,0,bitmap.getWidth(),bitmap.getHeight());
    int pixel=0;
    for (int i=0;i<size_images;++i){
        for (int j=0;j<size_images;++j){
            final int val=intValues[pixel++];
            if(quant==0){
                byteBuffer.putFloat((byte) ((val>>16)&0xFF));
                byteBuffer.putFloat((byte) ((val>>8)&0xFF));
                byteBuffer.putFloat((byte) (val&0xFF));
            }
            else {
                // paste this
                byteBuffer.putFloat((((val >> 16) & 0xFF))/255.0f);
                byteBuffer.putFloat((((val >> 8) & 0xFF))/255.0f);
                byteBuffer.putFloat((((val) & 0xFF))/255.0f);
            }
        }
    }
return byteBuffer;
}
```

The app opens to the camera but when a finger/hand is introduced, it terminates the app.

What changes should be done so that the app does not terminate?

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62866577/android-tflite-od-cannot-copy-to-a-tensorflowlite-tensor-normalized-input-i/62888294#62888294 It will give you some hints.