# Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer with 150528 bytes and a ByteBuffer with 602112 bytes

Tags: c#, tensorflow, xamarin, tensorflow-lite, image-classification

Im using xamarin form to create Image Classification which i got the documentation in xamarin blog.
but i got an error when passing image to bytebuffer, once the tensorflow-lite interpreter run the output i got an error saying "Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite buffer with 150528 bytes and a ByteBuffer with 602112 bytes."

Hope someone help me in this error. im little frustrated, thank you in advance. below is my code

```
    public class TensorflowClassifier : IClassify
    {
        //FloatSize is a constant with the value of 4 because a float value is 4 bytes
        const int FloatSize = 4;
        //PixelSize is a constant with the value of 3 because a pixel has three color channels: Red Green and Blue
        const int PixelSize = 3;


        public List<ImageClassificationModel> Classify(byte[] image)
        {
            var mappedByteBuffer = GetModelAsMappedByteBuffer();
            var interpreter = new Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite.Interpreter(mappedByteBuffer);

            //To resize the image, we first need to get its required width and height
            var tensor = interpreter.GetInputTensor(0);
            var shape = tensor.Shape();

            var width = shape[1];
            var height = shape[2];

            var byteBuffer = GetPhotoAsByteBuffer(image, width, height);

            //use StreamReader to import the labels from labels.txt
            var streamReader = new StreamReader(Application.Context.Assets.Open("labels.txt"));

            //Transform labels.txt into List<string>
            var labels = streamReader.ReadToEnd().Split('\n').Select(s => s.Trim()).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToList();

            //Convert our two-dimensional array into a Java.Lang.Object, the required input for Xamarin.TensorFlow.List.Interpreter
            var outputLocations = new float[1][] { new float[labels.Count] };
            var outputs = Java.Lang.Object.FromArray(outputLocations);

            interpreter.Run(byteBuffer, outputs);
            var classificationResult = outputs.ToArray<float[]>();

            //Map the classificationResult to the labels and sort the result to find which label has the highest probability
            var classificationModelList = new List<ImageClassificationModel>();

            for (var i = 0; i < labels.Count; i++)
            {
                var label = labels[i]; classificationModelList.Add(new ImageClassificationModel(label, classificationResult[0][i]));
            }

            return classificationModelList;
        }

        //Convert model.tflite to Java.Nio.MappedByteBuffer , the require type for Xamarin.TensorFlow.Lite.Interpreter
        private MappedByteBuffer GetModelAsMappedByteBuffer()
        {
            var assetDescriptor = Application.Context.Assets.OpenFd("model.tflite");
            var inputStream = new FileInputStream(assetDescriptor.FileDescriptor);

            var mappedByteBuffer = inputStream.Channel.Map(FileChannel.MapMode.ReadOnly, assetDescriptor.StartOffset, assetDescriptor.DeclaredLength);

            return mappedByteBuffer;
        }

        //Resize the image for the TensorFlow interpreter
        private ByteBuffer GetPhotoAsByteBuffer(byte[] image, int width, int height)
        {
            var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(image, 0, image.Length);
            var resizedBitmap = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);

            var modelInputSize = FloatSize * height * width * PixelSize;
            var byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.AllocateDirect(modelInputSize);
            byteBuffer.Order(ByteOrder.NativeOrder());

            var pixels = new int[width * height];
            resizedBitmap.GetPixels(pixels, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, 0, 0, resizedBitmap.Width, resizedBitmap.Height);

            var pixel = 0;

            //Loop through each pixels to create a Java.Nio.ByteBuffer
            for (var i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < height; j++)
                {
                    var pixelVal = pixels[pixel++];

                    byteBuffer.PutFloat(pixelVal >> 16 & 0xFF / 4);
                    byteBuffer.PutFloat(pixelVal >> 8 & 0xFF / 4);
                    byteBuffer.PutFloat(pixelVal & 0xFF / 4);
                }
            }

            bitmap.Recycle();

            return byteBuffer;
        }
    }
```

On my project i passed the byte array to the classifier

```
        private async void SaveImagePad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream image = await PadView.GetImageStreamAsync(SignatureImageFormat.Jpeg);
            //byte[] bytes = ReadFully(image);
            byte[] bytes = new byte[image.Length];
            image.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

            List<ImageClassificationModel> classifyImage = DependencyService.Get<IClassify>().Classify(bytes);


        }
```

Comment: Probably because you have floats you have to multiply the bytebuffer with 4. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62866577/android-tflite-od-cannot-copy-to-a-tensorflowlite-tensor-normalized-input-i/62888294#62888294

Comment: Thank you, already solved.  i realized that my model is uint8 input type but i passing float. so i create model with float input.